# How find/invoke appropriate handler for interface implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, handler, visitor-pattern

Suppose there is an interface with several implementations:

```
//methods and implementations are omitted
public interface MyRequest {}
```

And several handlers are extended from this interface:

```
public <T extends MyRequest> inteface Handler<> {
    MyResult handle(T request)
}

public XmlHandler implements Handler<XmlRequest> {
    @Override
    MyResult handle(XmlRequest request) {
        //...
    }
}

public JsonHandler implements Handler<JsonRequest> {
    @Override
    MyResult handle(JsonRequest request) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Up to this is clear, but the problem is that, when requests are parsed from parser with returns only interface:

```
public void  someMethod () {
    XmlHandler  xmlHandler = ...
    JsonHandler  jsonHandler = ...
    MyParser parser = ...
    MyRequest request = parser.parse(someObejct);

    if (request instanceof JsonRequest) {
        jsonHandler.handle(request);
    }

    if (request instanceof XmlRequest) {
        xmlHandler.handle(request);
    }

}
```

`instanceof` is very bad here. How do I avoid this?

My initial thought was to use visitor pattern here, e.g. put handlers into visito and define a dozen methods for each request type which invoke `handler.handle` method. And problem of course lies with the word `dozen`.

Is there a more elegant way to "select" handler for request call (or more elegant pattern then visitor)?

**P.S.** By the way, is the visitor pattern suitable here?

Comment: In your case `MyRequest` is marker interface and you have to use `instanceof` here to determine the actual type and then invoke method accordingly.

Comment: ´MyRequest` is not marker, methods ommited for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a good solution to this problem.

```
public interface MyRequestVisitor {
    public void handle(JsonRequest request);
    public void handle(XmlRequest request);
}

public interface MyRequest {
    public void handle(MyRequestVisitor visitor);
}

public class JsonRequest implements MyRequest  {
    public void handle(MyRequestVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.handle(this); // calls first handle method
    }
}

public class JsonRequest implements MyRequest  {
    public void handle(MyRequestVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.handle(this); // calls second handle method
    }
}
```

Then, in `someMethod`:

```
public void  someMethod () {
    XmlHandler  xmlHandler = ...
    JsonHandler  jsonHandler = ...
    MyParser parser = ...
    MyRequest request = parser.parse(someObejct);
    request.handle(new MyRequestVisitor() {
        public void handle(JsonRequest request) {
            jsonHandler.handle(request);
        }
        public void handle(XmlRequest request) {
            xmlHandler.handle(request);
        }
    });
```

If you add a new subclass called `NewRequest`, compiler forces you to implement `NewRequest.handle(MyRequestVisitor)`, which forces you to add a new `MyRequestVisitor.handle(NewRequest request)` method, which forces you to add it to the anonymous class too.

You can't not implement it, so you are safe, which the multi-way if-instanceof is not.